# Unexplained read error w/hosts.allow hostname lookup only

Tags: ssh, hosts

Yesterday I was locked out of a server with the error "`kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`" and I immediately found the cause after having connected over KVM that the hostname failed to match `hosts.allow` even though it does match.

```
sshd[717775]: warning: /etc/hosts.allow, line 10: can't verify hostname:
getaddrinfo (<correct-host.com>, AF_INET) failed
sshd[717775]: refused connect from <x.x.x.x> (x.x.x.x)
```

The same happens over a different ISP from a different location that is also allowed but denied for the same reason.

However, the odd thing about it is, that both lines 10 and 11 for each ISP's entry are reported as `"line 10" in /var/log/auth.log` where it fails to connect -- note that there are no characters, including spaces, preceding or succeeding line 10 that may render it "unreadable" and cause line 11 to not be read.

Note that hosts still fail with the traditional format "`sshd: .isp1.com .isp2.com`" (the only reason I've configured this way is to change service access per host on a per-line basis should I want to).

As mentioned, it fails to read the first uncommented line (10), regardless of the order of hosts listed or which domain I'm connecting from:

```
sshd[3626087]: warning: /etc/hosts.allow, line 10: can't verify hostname: getaddrinfo(different-but-correct-host.com), AF_INET) failed
sshd[717775]: refused connect from <x.x.x.x> (<x.x.x.x>)
```

Note that the IPs x.x.x.x are correct as well and reverse DNS resolves the hostnames in full, including the ".isp1.com" and ".isp2.com" domains necessary to resolve and allow the connections.  If I change the order of the hosts, it makes no difference - line 10 fails first and neither connection is allowed.  It **will allow** IP entries.

I can connect with `hosts.allow` list just the IP address of the inbound connection - this is specifically DNS-related, but no known DNS faults exist with the provider at this time; a different DNS provider was tested and works fine as best I can tell as well.

This configuration has been operational as configured for many months and the only changes were updates from their main and ESM resources.  That is where I believe the problem lies as DNS appears to be operational.

The last successful login I recall before the issue, updates were applied:

```
Log started: 2024-03-15  06:50:32
(Reading database ... ^M(Reading database ... 5%^M(Reading database ... 10%^M(Reading database ... 15%^M(Reading database ... 20%^M(Reading database ... 25%^M(Reading database ... 30%^M(Reading database ... 35%^M(Reading database ... 40%^M(Reading database ... 45%^M(Reading database ... 50%^M(Reading database ... 5>
Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1-dev_2.4.7-1ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1-dev:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.3) over (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1_2.4.7-1ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.3) over (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up libexpat1-dev:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
Log ended: 2024-03-15  06:50:52
```

It's possible it was updated beforehand:

```
Log started: 2024-03-13  18:34:36
(Reading database ... ^M(Reading database ... 5%^M(Reading database ... 10%^M(Reading database ... 15%^M(Reading database ... 20%^M(Reading database ... 25%^M(Reading database ... 30%^M(Reading database ... 35%^M(Reading database ... 40%^M(Reading database ... 45%^M(Reading database ... 50%^M(Reading database ... 5>
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-advantage-tools_31.2~22.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-advantage-tools (31.2~22.04) over (30~22.04) ...
^[[1mdpkg:^[[0m ^[[1;33mwarning:^[[0m unable to delete old directory '/var/lib/ubuntu-advantage': Directory not empty
^[[1mdpkg:^[[0m ^[[1;33mwarning:^[[0m unable to delete old directory '/etc/ubuntu-advantage': Directory not empty
Selecting previously unselected package ubuntu-pro-client.
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-pro-client_31.2~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-pro-client (31.2~22.04) ...
Setting up ubuntu-pro-client (31.2~22.04) ...
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (31.2~22.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Log ended: 2024-03-13  18:35:09

Log started: 2024-03-13  18:42:57
(Reading database ... ^M(Reading database ... 5%^M(Reading database ... 10%^M(Reading database ... 15%^M(Reading database ... 20%^M(Reading database ... 25%^M(Reading database ... 30%^M(Reading database ... 35%^M(Reading database ... 40%^M(Reading database ... 45%^M(Reading database ... 50%^M(Reading database ... 5>
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-pro-client-l10n_31.2~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-pro-client-l10n (31.2~22.04) over (30~22.04) ...
Setting up ubuntu-pro-client-l10n (31.2~22.04) ...
Log ended: 2024-03-13  18:43:12

Log started: 2024-03-13  18:43:35
(Reading database ... ^M(Reading database ... 5%^M(Reading database ... 10%^M(Reading database ... 15%^M(Reading database ... 20%^M(Reading database ... 25%^M(Reading database ... 30%^M(Reading database ... 35%^M(Reading database ... 40%^M(Reading database ... 45%^M(Reading database ... 50%^M(Reading database ... 5>
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-utils_2.4.52-1ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-utils (2.4.52-1ubuntu4.8) over (2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7) ...
Setting up apache2-utils (2.4.52-1ubuntu4.8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Log ended: 2024-03-13  18:43:41
```

If anyone has any idea why this has occurred, I'd like to fix it as there are only two connections from two ISPs that ever need to connect over ssh, and the rest are expressly denied via `hosts.deny`.  Since no matter, the format, and it's only DNS-related entries that aren't being parsed correctly (it appears), I'm left with few leads.

Bare IP works, but the connecting hosts don't have static IPs, so, unfortunately, it cannot be used in that preferred manner.